# c++ midi library that works on ndk

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, midi

I need a library to use to export some music info that I have in c++ to a midi file (needs to work in Android ndk).

I am afraid tse3 is to big for the Android platform and I would prefer a smaller library, but I do not know one. Is there a way for me to export a midi file from c++ through ndk Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a lightweight Java MIDI library compatible with Android if you want. It's not NDK like you want, but you can pretty easily build a MIDI file from whatever data you have.

http://code.google.com/p/android-midi-lib/